# Change default value of width argument in shiny::renderPlot

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say I want to change the default value of `width` in `shiny::renderPlot` to `500`. How can I do that?

Below is my try with defining `customRenderPlot` function but it doesn't react to input changes later on.

```
library(shiny)

customRenderPlot <- function(plot, width = 500) {
  renderPlot(plot, width = width)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "bins",
    label = "Number of bins:",
    value = 2
  ),
  plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- customRenderPlot({
    x <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```